# Run Command Prompt Through Python (Or Vice Versa)

Tags: python-3.x

I found myself doing a repetitive task and wondered how I can automate it.

I can write a function script with python(3), to iterate through each item in a folder, but I'm not sure how I would run that through command prompt.

[image]

I have sort of looked into how it would be possible, but I think a direct response to my exact question would be more helpful and easier to grasp.

My question comes more from a desire to learn than it does from laziness!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `os.system`, but `subprocess.run` is probably better. You should also use `glob`:

```
import glob
import subprocess

files = glob.glob('*.wav')

for file in files:
    subprocess.run(['xWMAEncode', file, file.replace('.wav', '.xwm')])
```